# Is it possible to use some of the features in maui-community-toolkit together with Blazor MAUI?

Tags: maui-community-toolkit

Thinking of MVVM and using ObservableObject, ObservableProperty and more. It seems like Blazor MAUI and the toolkit use incompatible partial classes. Gets error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'NameOfPage' must not specify different base classes.

I'm trying to use the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel, I also tried to inherit the same base class in the Page as in the NameOfPage.razor.cs (and also NameOfPage.cs) file but with no result. If it is not possible or currently out of the scope for this project, would this be an improvement, or are there any workarounds or guidance for using the toolkit with Blazor MAUI or other similar ways to do this?